# Не получается вывести JSON в HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

Пробую сделать расписание по дням недели.

Собственно проблема с выводом в переменную newContent

Может кто знает, в чем подвох?

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
             
            if(xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {
                responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                actualDateTime = responseObject.ActualDateTime;
           
                var newContent = '';
                for (var i=0; i<=responseObject.Data.length; i++) {
                    newContent += '<div class="event"><p>'+ responseObject.Data[i].BeginTime + '</p></div>';
                }
                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = newContent;
                
            }
        };
        xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.fitpass.ru/api/lesson/timetable?club=308', true);
        xhr.send(null);
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: responseObject.Data[2].BeginTime  - если вместо счетчика поставить число, то вывод работает, правда с одним только значением

Comment: Кстати, зря вы вопрос редактируете и поправляете. Так теряется взаимосвязь моего ответа и вашего вопроса)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас банальная опечатка, вместо `length` написано `lenght`.

Также, у вас не верное условие в цикле. Нужно использовать *строгое неравенство* `<`. Потому что если использовать *нестрогое неравенство* `<=`, то у вас будет выход за границы массива.

Что бы такого не повторялось рекомендую использовать какую-нибудь **IDE** или хороший текстовый редактор, типа **SublimeText**.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {

  if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {
    responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    actualDateTime = responseObject.ActualDateTime;

    var newContent = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < responseObject.Data.length; i++) {
      newContent += '<div class="event"><p>' + responseObject.Data[i].BeginTime + '</p></div>';
    }
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = newContent;

  }
};
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.fitpass.ru/api/lesson/timetable?club=308', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Да спасибо, действительно, не заметил.
Но после правки в консоле ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'BeginTime' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload

Comment: @Pasha Внимательно посмотрите на мой ответ, у вас условие в цикле не верное `i<=responseObject.Data.lenght`. Впрочем, я сейчас это еще в ответе напишу.

Comment: Исправил условие в вопросе

Comment: Вы были правы, все заработало, спасибо

Comment: @Pasha Если мой ответ вам помог, пожалуйста, примите его как правильный.

Answer (score 0):

У вас опечатка, вместо `lenght` надо `length`